# Download base64/blob format image from HTML on Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, canvas

I write a HTML+JavaScript program.
I render image on my HTML pages by Canvas.
And then I want to download it from browser.
PC and iOS is OK, but Android browser is not ok
**Is there any way to make the android phone's browser download the base64/blob image?**
**thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: what do you mean by "Android browser"? Chrome for Android? Firefox for Android? UC Browser for Android? Samsung Internet? etc ... I don't think there's a thing called "Android browser" - link to it if there is - Does your code work on all PC browsers? Perhaps your code is written in a browser specific way that prevents this mythical "Android browser" from working the same way

Comment: What happens when you try on this unscpecified mobile browser? What code are you using?